# Add a member in google group using directory api by a non admin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Is it possible to add a new member to a group, when you are the owner of the group but not the admin user using google app script.

Comment: As per [Directory API: Group Members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#create_member), OWNER – This role can change send messages to the group, add or remove members, change member roles, change group's settings, and delete the group. An OWNER must be a member of the group.

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about the member roles, see the [administration help center](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?answer=167094).

There are 3 roles specified that the administrator can assign. Specifically, Group Owner, Group Manager and Group Member.

If you are a group owner, here are the the privileges:

> - Send messages to the group
> - Add or remove group members
> - Change member roles—for example, from member to owner
> - Change any of the group's settings
> - Delete the group

From what was stated, as a Group Owner, you have the power to add a Group Member

Visit the documentation to know more about [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members).

Comment: I had already tried it. The account I'm using is the owner of the group but the problem is that it is not an admin account. Due to a non admin account I'm not allowed to use admin sdk functionality. So I want to use admin sdk functionality with an non admin account. How can I do that.